# load JSON data into a dataframe

Tags: r, json, loops

I am a beginner working with R and especially JSON files, and this is probably a simple question but I have been unsuccessful for a while.

Here is a sample row of data from a provided text file (there are ~4000 rows):

{"040070005001":4,"040070005003":4,"040138101003":4,"040130718024":4}

Each row has a variable number of values in the string.

I am trying to use a function, but it is only loading the last row of the data set rather than capturing the data from each row?

```
For (row in 1:nrow(origins)) {
 json <- origins$home_cbgs[row] %>% 
      fromJSON() %>% 
      unlist() %>% 
      as.data.frame() %>% 
      rownames_to_column() %>% 
      rename(
        origin_census_block_group = "rowname",
        origin_visitors = "."
  )
}
```

Comment: You are overwriting `json`every time the loop repeats, so only the last version is stored. You could try making `json` as an empty list and writing to `json[[row]]` during every iteration. At the end you will have a list of data frames. If they all have the same columns you can do `json <- do.call("rbind", json)` to stick them together into one data frame.

Comment: That solved it. I wrote the resulting record into a separate data frame using rbind() and it appended all the records into the table. Thanks for the direction!

Comment: In a newly sent file there was an additional element. The first column has an identifier and the second field holds the JSON string described above. I would like that identifier to be a part of each row to link the two JSON fields back to those locations. Would I use a nested loop to get that first field and then parse out the JSON string?